# How to show Terminal window for SDL application in Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, sdl, clang++

I'm building my SDL project from a makefile (using clang++ compiler) into a .app bundle, which works great. I'm not using an IDE.

Now I'd like to open a separate terminal window alongside the graphics window, every time I run my app, which captures std::cout for debugging purposes. How to go about this? Any flags I should pass to the compiler?

Comment: App bundles are something you create when you're ready to release a project. If you're still debugging, there's no reason to package your project into an app bundle.

Comment: Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @MrEricSir Some application frameworks such as CEF3 "chromium embedded framework" require the bundle structure with resources and framework inside to run, even if you are just debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out .app bundles don't open a terminal window. Just open the executable the compiler created from the command line and it opens the SDL app alongside a terminal window.